# Is there a way to pass all the entity columns on a transaction to a EntitySubscriberInterface in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have a query that I'm running using a transaction and a subscriber that is listening to any updates, the query below updates the booking entity status

```
await this.connection.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    booking = await transactionalEntityManager
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(Booking)
      .set({
        status: BookingStatus.BOOKED,
        editor,
      })
      .where({
        bookingUuid: In(bookingUuids),
      })
      .returning("*")
      .execute();
```

The query above also returns the results with the **returning(*)** keyword, the raw SQL results look like this

```
UPDATE "bookings" SET "status" = $1, "editor" = $2, "updated_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE "bookingUuid" IN ($3, $4) RETURNING * -- PARAMETERS: [booked","localauth","ae241869-6692-41cf-a2a9-650e591a85cc","867fa182-3ea1-4b89-bef8-70a75b9ab346"]
```

The issue is on a subscribers, that calls after the update I need to get all the columns of the booking entity, (this is for some post update operations that are conducted **afterUpdate**). But I can only access the **event.entity** columns and that is restricted to only the affected columns (in this case **status** and **editor**), the parameters are not included (the 2 bookingUuids). And certainly not the rest of the columns in booking.

```
async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<Booking>): Promise<void> {
if (event.entity.status === BookingStatus.BOOKED) {
  console.log(event);
```

I have been through the documentation throughout and cannot find any use-case that attempts to solve this, is there something I am missing, should a ORM be expected to be able to do something like this ?

Comment: You figure this out OP?